# How to show a window from a PyQt5 app already running? self.show()

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have an app with several windows already working, but I don't really understand the concept.
I have a window with a QPushButton:

```
 self.ui.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
```

And this code below, which works very nicely if used alone. (example to show a graph)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar


class ScrollableWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, fig):
        self.qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.widget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.widget.layout().setSpacing(0)

        self.fig = fig
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.canvas)

        self.nav = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.widget)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.nav)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.scroll)

        self.show()
        exit(self.qapp.exec_())


# create a figure and some subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=5, figsize=(16,16))
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.plot([2,3,5,1])

# pass the figure to the custom window
a = ScrollableWindow(fig)
```

What I would like to do, is to put this code inside my function

```
def btn_clicked(self):
   # here copy this nice code
```

To show up the graph once I clicked on the button.

But obviously, **exit(self.qapp.exec_())** can't be used otherwise the common error is showing up:

QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

So I delete that line of code, but then it is not working either.
Here I dont understand why. My app is already running, MainWindow is showing up normally, why isn't it possible to show some other window, without using **exec_()**

**self.show()** should theoretically show up the graph isn't it?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks everyone.

To provide a very simple application example which could be used by everyone, I join this pyqt5 code with 1 PushButton.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(437, 239)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 151, 41))
        self.btn.setObjectName("btn")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

    def btn_clicked(self):
        # here I would like to use the code from above to show a graph



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: hi, my example is not reproducible? thx  (I'm beginner)

Comment: the idea is to use the code i shown to get a nice ScrollableWindow, which can show huge graphs no problem, can scroll up and down.